# How to prove? $0<\left(n^2-1\right)^n(n+1)<n^{2n+1}$

Tags: inequality

$$
\displaystyle 0<\left(n^2-1\right)^n(n+1)<n^{2n+1}
$$

> How does one prove this inequality for $n>1\in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: If you write out the expansion of the first inequality using the Binomial Theorem, you will find that even after subtracting off $n^{2n+1}$, there will be terms left which go to negative infinity

Comment: @AlfredYerger Great idea using the Binomial Theorem. I bet the Binomial Theorem can be used as the basis of an inductive proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(n^2-1)^n\cdot (n+1) = (n-1)^n\cdot (n+1)^{n+1} < n^{2n+1} \iff \left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n\cdot \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1} < 1 \iff n\cdot ln\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right) + (n+1)\cdot ln\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right) < 0 \iff \dfrac{ln(1-\dfrac{1}{n})}{\dfrac{1}{n}} + ln(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}) + \dfrac{ln(1 + \dfrac{1}{n})}{\dfrac{1}{n}} < 0$.

Let $x = \dfrac{1}{n}$, then $0 < x < 1$, and the inequality to be proven is:
$\dfrac{ln(1-x^2)}{x} + ln(1 + x) < 0 \iff \dfrac{ln(1-x^2) + xln(1+x)}{x} < 0$. To complete the proof, we show: $f(x) < 0$ with $f(x) = ln(1-x^2) + xln(1+x)$ on $(0,1)$. Thus:

$f'(x) = -\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2} + ln(1+x) + \dfrac{x}{1+x} = ln(1+x) - \dfrac{x}{1-x} = g(x)$. Observe that if $f'(x) < 0$, then $f(x) < f(0) = 0$, and we're done. So we need to show again that: $f'(x) = g(x) < 0$ on $(0,1)$.

To get this, differentiate $g$ and have:

$g'(x) = \left(ln(1+x) + 1 + \dfrac{1}{x-1}\right)' = \dfrac{1}{1+x} - \dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2} =\dfrac{x(x-3)}{(1+x)(1-x)^2} < 0$. Thus: $g(x) < g(0) = 0$, and we're done.

Comment: I tried the same idea without the change of variable to x. However, I gave up after the first derivative thinking it was going in circles. It's amazing how you eliminated all the Logs. Thanks for the proof.

Comment: @cyclochaotic: cheers.

Answer (score 5):

The LHS is immediate since all the terms are positive.

The RHS follows from [AM-GM](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean-am-gm/). We have

$$ (n^2-1)^n (n^2+n) < \left( \frac{n \times (n^2 -1) +1 \times  (n^2+n)}{n+1} \right) ^{n+1} =  (n^2)^{n+1}. $$

We have strict inequality since not all the terms are equal.

Cancel 1 factor of $n$ from both sides.

Comment: Thank you for adding the extra step. I see it now. This is the first time I've seen an inequality proven with AM-GM; what an amazing tool. It took me a little while to figure out what the x's where, x[1]=(n*n-1), x[2]=(n*n-1), ... x[n]=(n*n-1), x[n+1]=(n*n+1). It is bizarre that it simply falls into place perfectly! Thanks again.